# How can I leave the desktop locked while using VNC to connect to a remote Windows machine?

Tags: windows, vnc

I want to leave the desktop locked while using VNC to connect to a remote Windows machine.

Normally I believe when you VNC and unlock the desktop the physical server's desktop is also unlocked. I don't want that.

Anyway to prevent it?

Answer (score 3):

RealVNC can do that. I haven't checked other VNC distributions.

From [VNC Server Free Edition 4.1 for Windows](http://www.realvnc.com/products/free/4.1/winvnc.html) :

> **Disable local inputs while server is in use**
>
> ```
> DisableLocalInputs=true/false
> ```
>
> The mouse and keyboard physically
>   attached to the server computer can be
>   disabled for the duration of a remote
>   connection, preventing local users
>   from interacting with the computer.

[image]